# How to change time format that is already stored in json using python?

Tags: python, pandas, milliseconds

I have data stored in a JSON file and am reading it in with Pandas. The format of the time is `'Jun 10, 2021, 01:05:30:565'`. I would like to present the time column with its match. However, python gives this error: `Unknown string format:', 'Jun 10, 2021, 01:05:30:565 AM')`.

I used: `DS [pd.to_datetime(day + ' ' + time)] = value`

That line worked with other columns that have time : HH:MM: SS. but with milliseconds I'm unable to present what I want.

Comment: Welcome @DoaaA. Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['Jun 10, 2021, 01:05:30:565 AM']}, 
...                   index = [0]) 
>>> df
    date
0   Jun 10, 2021, 01:05:30:565 AM
```

We can convert the `date` column to `DateTime` like so :

```py
>>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%b %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S:%f %p")
>>> df
    date
0   2021-06-10 01:05:30.565
```